# http get from the shell in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, shell, http

I'd like to download a link like:

http://example.org/file.mp3

Now, I'm enough of a shell junkie to know what SCP does, but that's about where my geek-dom ends.  So is there a shell program that lets me basically do an http get and pipe it through to a file?

Comment: @fakeit If you respond to comments by other users, let them know by writing @PrefixOfUsername in your comment, e.g. *@Daniel*, *@Dan*, *@fakeit* or *@fake*. This way, they get notified by SuperUser. *@Beck* is close, but doesn't work.

Comment: @Daniel Ah, thanks for the advice.  So, won't everyone with "Daniel" in their prefix get notified too?  Or is it smart and only looks for "Daniel's" that have answered / commented?

Comment: At most a single person is ever notified through this @-functionality (so no notifying 20 people by filling your comment with @'s), plus always the person you authored the post on which you comment (that's why you're notified about this comment without an @ to you). It looks backward in time in the same comment thread and takes the most recent matching user. If a "Dan" were to comment here, he and I would be competing for any `@Dan` notifications by others, `@Daniel` would go to me though. The prefix must have 3 or more characters, `@fa` won't work.

Comment: @Daniel Awesome.  Thanks for all your help today.  You rock.

Comment: These days simply use curl for this.  Just type `curl http://whatever` that's it

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
wget http://example.org/file.mp3
```

(you might need to install it e.g. using [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew), MacPorts or Fink -- assuming you're still on Mac OS X)

Alternatively, you can use `curl`, which is standard on Mac OS X:

```
curl http://example.org/file.mp3 > local_filename.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

Wget and curl may be not installed on some Unix-like system's by default. But you also can use: 
`fetch http://example.org/file.mp3` 

it save response to the current directory with URL filename. To change see `man fetch`