# How do I download a file using the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, download

I want to download a file from the Linux command line. Basically I'm using `ssh` and I'm trying to download a file to my file system on my laptop. How can I do that from the command line?

Answer (score 24):

`wget` and `curl` are commonly used for web URLs.  For remote files, use `scp` for individual files and consider `rsync` for directories.

Comment: or `scp -r` for directories

Comment: [Don't you just love the free rep that comes from answering these questions?](http://superuser.com/questions/225338/http-get-from-the-shell-in-mac-os-x/225340#225340)

Comment: IME rsync is better for both files and directories - if available - apart from anything else it can cope with resumes efficiently.

Comment: Agreed; `scp -r` mostly aggravates me when I make the mistake of trying to use it.

Comment: I am trying to download eclipse (http://212.219.56.184/sites/download.eclipse.org/eclipseMirror/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR2/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32.zip) in linux using command line. But I get "Connecting to 212.219.56.184:80... failed: Connection refused"... Any Idea of what the issue is all about?

Answer (score 14):

If the file is publicly available, then:

```
wget http://example.com/file.tar
```

Comment: [This](http://lifehacker.com/#!161202/geek-to-live--mastering-wget) article explains how to use different options available for wget . Sengar +1 for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted zengr's answer, but would like to mention (since your question is a bit vague) `lynx` or `links` web browsers as well, if you don't remember the full URL to the file to download.

`scp` with public key authentication is your friend if you copy between your own machines.