# How to remotely download any file from the Internet?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, vpn, download, remote

Is it possible to download a file over VPN via the command line in Ubuntu 12.04.1?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer? Additionally, could you provide me with a info or link to how to do it by command line?

Comment: No, I made my point before you edited your post, I didn't know it was via Ubuntu and command line. I updated your question, as it was clearly not asking the correct question. If this is OK, I will delete my other question as it's no longer relevant.

Comment: Having a VPN or not is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/261154/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-the-command-line IMO

Comment: Thank you very much, Nifle and others. I used wget and it works, my misuderstanding about simple wget command and VPN  was in action.

Comment: I found this useful video-sample of music downloading http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWG2raIcVxQ

Comment: please don't edit the answer to question, add an additional answer if needed

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) or [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget).

Example for Wget:

```
$ wget http://yoururlgoeshere.file
```

For more information:

```
$ man wget
```

If Wget isn't installed, use this command first to install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wget
```

Comment: He is obviously new at this. Would you consider adding an example or two? And perhaps link to (or tell him how find it himself) the manpages.

Comment: $ man wget
$ wget http://yoururlgoeshere.file
if its not installed:
$ sudo apt-get install wget

Comment: Thanks to all, due to your advises I've done that I wanted