# How to download flv using Linux command line?

Tags: download, remote, flv

I frequently need to download a video from a varieties of  websites on a remote Linux server. So wondering if there is an easy command/tool to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [http get from the shell in Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/225338/http-get-from-the-shell-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the URL and aren't looking for anything terribly complex, wget works just fine (I use it on linux and windows for large downloads).

```
wget http://www.site.com/stuff.flv
```

Comment: In know how to use wget for this simple scenario, but what if the webpages's url does not end with stuff.flv (as often it does not)?

Comment: `wget -O stuff.flv http://www.site.com/get_stuff.php?video_id=99`