# Download MP3 from URL on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mp3

Ok, so i have a URL of an MP3. What are my options for downloading it. In or out of a browser, doesn't really matter. Short of creating a HTML document with a `href` that i "Save Target" on, can I do anything from the Terminal or within Mac OS X? I know Linux has `wget`...

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/225338/http-get-from-the-shell-in-mac-os-x/225340#225340). There's also `wget` on OS X.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Paste the URL into Safari's address bar
2. Type <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Try `curl -O http://url/of/file.mp3`

Answer (score 2):

Paste the URL into Safari's Downloads window.

Answer (score 0):

Actually downloading MP3 is not legal. You'd better purchase this MP3 on iTunes or other webs.

If you insist getting it download, try to use Listen to YouTube. Enter this URL into **listentoYouTube.com**, you can download this MP3 free immediately. I think the theory is just to convert the video file to audio file.

Or try a third party application on Mac OS X. Like MP3 Rocket, but it doesn't support Mac OS, so try Any MP3 Downloader. Just search the song name and other information and get them downloaded, also for free.

Source: http://www.anymp3downloader.com

Comment: Where did you get the idea that downloading MP3 isn't legal?  The source you list is a product web site for downloader software.

Comment: It's a website for downloading a MP3 downloader tool. And sometimes downloading MP3 can be illegal. (The file format mp3 is legal, while the music's copyright protection is being broken.) This might be confused. Refer to: http://www.worldlawdirect.com/article/1395/downloading-music-legal.html

Comment: You may have misinterpreted the link in your comment, & the source in your answer is a site pushing downloader software. Yes, there are some MP3 links that are unauthorized offers to share, but most are not.  The question doesn't even mention a specific file, so your answer is sort of a non sequitur.  A blanket statement like the first sentence is incorrect.  I'm sort of surprised that it never attracted downvotes.  I don't recall how I stumbled across your answer a year later, other than maybe it was in a review queue because somebody flagged it.  If it was mine, I'd consider deleting it.